Laravel still uses database table for cache despite setting redis for caching
from the documentation I setup redis for the cache. But whenever I try hitting any end point, it gives me error for not ebing able to find the table cache in the database. I want only redis to be used not database but I'm not sure what else is missing in the configuration files.
These are the files I have. for instance in the config/database
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
return [
    'default' =>'mysql',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [ ... ],
    ],
    'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => '6379'
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => '6379',
        ],
    ],
];

in the config/cache.php I have the following:
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

return [
    'default' => env('CACHE_STORE', 'redis'),
    "driver" => env("CACHE_DRIVER", "redis"),
    'stores' => [
        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => env('REDIS_CACHE_CONNECTION', 'cache'),
            'lock_connection' => env('REDIS_CACHE_LOCK_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
        ],
    ],
    'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', 'MYT')
];

whenever I try to hit any endpoint I get the following error
{
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mytable.cache' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `cache` where `key` = MYTilluminate:foundation:down limit 1)",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
"file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
"line": 813,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 767,
        "function": "runQueryCallback",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 398,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2996,
        "function": "select",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2981,
        "function": "runSelect",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 3569,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2980,
        "function": "onceWithColumns",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php",
        "line": 343,
        "function": "get",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/DatabaseStore.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "first",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php",
        "line": 116,
        "function": "get",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cache\\DatabaseStore",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php",
        "line": 85,
        "function": "get",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/CacheBasedMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 75,
        "function": "has",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
        "line": 65,
        "function": "active",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\CacheBasedMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 183,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
        "line": 49,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 183,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 183,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 119,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 175,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 144,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
        "line": 1188,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/public/index.php",
        "line": 17,
        "function": "handleRequest",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/projects/mytable/api2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
        "line": 23,
        "function": "require_once"
    }
]
}


In your config/cache.php, add 'database' => '0'' to default array where you have prefix and etc...

Did you try running php artisan config:cache or php artisan config:clear after making changes to the config?

Did you try to clear the cache ? just use php artisan cache:clear or php artisan config:clear

The issue is likely caused by Laravel's Maintenance Mode. It uses a dedicated configuration setting to determine which store is queried when checking if the maintenance mode is currently active.
You can find these settings under the maintenance key in your app.php config file:
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Maintenance Mode Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These configuration options determine the driver used to determine and
    | manage Laravel's "maintenance mode" status. The "cache" driver will
    | allow maintenance mode to be controlled across multiple machines.
    |
    | Supported drivers: "file", "cache"
    |
    */

    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER', 'file'),
        'store' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE', 'database'),
    ],


You want to set cache as the maintenance mode driver and redis as the store, like so:
    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER', 'cache'),
        'store' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE', 'redis'),
    ],

Alternatively you can use environment variables to set both values:
APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=cache
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=redis

Run the php artisan config:clear command after changing the settings and the issue should be resolved.

yes it worked, thanks!
